# Using JSDoc with Adobe ExtendScript

Tags: adobe, jsdoc, extendscript

I'm developing scripts for Adobe.
Adobe is using it's own language called ExtendScript, which is essentially ECMAScript 3 with custom C-style preprocessor directives starting with the **#**

```
#include "file.jsxinc" //includes a file more like require  
#includepath "lib" //tells ESTK to include files that follow from a given folder   
#include "fileFromLibFolder.jsx" //file is included from "lib" folder
```

As well as some other # directives that may be safely ignored.
  JSDoc by default returns an error when it gets to the first **#**:

> Unexpected token ILLEGAL

I was unable to find a ready made JSDoc extension for ExtendScript. 
Maybe you could point me to a possible solution on how to make JSDoc work for this case?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `//@ include` instead of `#include`. Not sure, where this is originally documented, but I found it in this [Github post](https://github.com/basiljs/basil.js/issues/34).